# SemaphoreSlim usage limitations

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/threading/semaphore-and-semaphoreslim) says:

> The SemaphoreSlim class represents a lightweight, fast semaphore that can be used for waiting within a single process *when wait times are expected to be very short*.

What does *very short* mean? Does anybody know explicit time value in milliseconds? Is it possible to use a `SemaphoreSlim` instance, if wait time will be about 5 minutes?

Comment: The non-slim Semaphore always makes an OS kernel call.  The slim flavor avoids it if it can (no blocking).  That call took about 200 nanoseconds the last time I measured it.  So you'll be ahead when it is less.  You can't notice the difference when it is milliseconds or minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a `SemaphoreSlim` instance, if wait time will be about 5 minutes?

Yes, that's fine.

The documentation should not be read to mean that `SemaphoreSlim` is to be used *only* when wait times are expected to be very short. Rather that it's more suitable for such situations than the heavier-weight alternative [`Semaphore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore).

What constitutes "very short"? Hard to say, since it's dependent on what else is going on in the code. But I'd put it in the tens of milliseconds range, possibly as long as hundreds of milliseconds. Once you're talking about seconds or longer, I would expect there to be no significant advantage of the one over the other.

If your wait times are significantly longer, then the overheads of allocating and managing the `Semaphore` class as compared to the `SemaphoreSlim` class are likely not to be significant in the overall profile of your executing code. So you can easily get away with using `Semaphore` in such situations without significantly impacting the performance of your code, even though it's technically less efficient.

Personally, I use `SemaphoreSlim` instead of `Semaphore` always, except where I need a feature of the latter that the former doesn't support. That doesn't come up very often, and even less now with the even-higher abstractions available in C# and .NET for coordinating concurrently running code. Even using a semaphore at all has become somewhat of a rarity for me.

Comment: Thanks. So, does it mean a `Semaphore` instance may lock thead longer than it's required and therefore, if wait times are expected to be very short, then it recommends to use `SemaphoreSlim` instead?

Comment: I haven't seen any measurable difference in "lock" times. Presumably, you are talking about the latency between when a semaphore is released and another thread which was waiting on it acquires it. Generally, the major bottleneck there won't be the synchronization object, but rather the Windows thread scheduler. Once a thread has acquired a lock, it still does not necessarily run right away. ...

Comment: ... It is put into the "runnable" state, and then will get its turn along with any other threads, when the OS thread scheduler grants the thread some CPU time. In that context, any overhead in the synchronization object itself is likely to be relatively insignificant.